# Two for loops and an if statement inside it

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, for-loop, break

My code is something like this:-

```
for() //outer for
{
   for() //inner for
   {
      if()
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

If the break statement executes the next execution will be of which for loop?
I know this is a very abstract question but I really don't have time to write the full code. Thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing like an 'if-loop', `break` will only affect the nearest innermost loop block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` will break the inner for `**loop**` only. **It breaks the closest loop ONLY where it was called.**

In your example, if your `if` condition is satisfied, it will stop iterations of the inner for loop and move back(continue) the outer for loop.

Answer (score 4):

The `break` statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing `do`, `for`, `switch`, or `while` statement in which it appears.  In this case, that means breaking out of the inner `for` only.

**Edit:**  Standard Reference:  **6.6.1 The break statement [stmt.break]**

> 1 The break statement shall occur only in an iteration-statement or a
>   switch statement and causes termination of the smallest enclosing
>   iteration-statement or switch statement; control passes to the
>   statement following the terminated statement, if any.

Comment: So won't it break out of if?

Comment: @PrakharMohan see my comment. That taken, the term 'scope' is not precisely used in this answer.

Comment: @PrakharMohan - "The break statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing do, for, switch, or while statement in which it appears"

Answer (score 1):

You can use goto to break the outer loop as well if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a way to break the outer loop as the `break` will only leave its enclosing scope.  What you use to manage state can be anything, but in its most simple form you can just use a boolean and check for that as well as your original condition in the outermost loop.

```
bool breakLoop = false;
for(...; ... && !breakLoop; ...) //outer for
{
   for() //inner for
   {
      if()
      {
         breakLoop = true;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Really?? Your code example is far from being correct (especially the condition in the outer for)

Comment: @g-makulik: I had to write the response quickly and made a minor typo, relax.

Comment: @g-makulik: ahh, yeah, that was copied from the OP (which was subsequently edited and removed).  I just didn't see it.